# How to assign a function to a class member that is pointer to a function?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a class:

```
struct Twister()
{
   double (*myF)(double x);
}
```

I have defined a function:

```
double Tester(double a)
{
   return 2*a;
}
```

How do I assign the pointer `myF` to the value `Tester`?

Comment: `twister_instance.myF = &Tester;`

Comment: @Jarod42 You don't need the `&`

Comment: How do you usually assign _anything_? This question shows an abject lack of prior research.

Comment: Thanks for the help and yes, the & is not needed. I tried figuring out on my own but couldn't. I am new at this so apologies if this was too obvious.

Answer (score 1):

> *"How do I assign the pointer myF the value Tester??"*

Simply in your class constructor's member initializer list:

```
double Tester(double a){ return 2*a;}

class Twister {
public:
    double(*myF)(double x);
    Twister() : myF(Tester) {}
};
```

Also for sake of encapsulation you should make the `myF` member variable `private`, and provide a constructor to initialize the function pointer member:

```
class Twister {
    double(*myF)(double x);
public:
    Twister(double(*f)(double)) : myF(f) {}
};
```

Use it like:

```
Twister twister(Tester);
```

Additionally you can provide a setter function (and a `typedef`, to make it easier to write), if you want to change the function pointer, during the lifetime of `Twister`:

```
class Twister {
public:
    typedef double(*FnPtrType)(double);

    Twister(FnPtrType f) : myF(f) {}
    void setMyF(FnPtrType f) { myF = f; }

private:
    FnPtrType myF;
};
```